# How to resize the height of a ReactJS component according to the height of the parent div?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a React component (Cartouche in the code) that I call x times in a div, depending on what div in which I call it.
For example, I have a div with height:690px and another with height:450px and I call the same component x times in each div, depending on the div.
I want the component to resize for it fit perfectly in each div.

Already try to change component size in CSS with % but it doesn't work.

```html
//Component

export default function Cartouche(props) {

    return (
        <div style={{ width: '100%', backgroundColor: '#E5E2E2', marginTop: '2%', marginBottom: '5%', borderRadius: 30, height: 'auto' }}>
            <div style={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>{props.data.STRING_1}</div><br />
            <div style={{ textTransform: 'uppercase' }}>{props.data.STRING_2}</div>
            <div style={{ border: 'solid 1px black', width: '25%', position: 'absolute', zIndex: '-1', height: 20, marginLeft: '2%', borderRadius: '0 0 10px 10px' }}>
                <div style={{ position: "absolute", bottom: 3, left: 5 }}>
                    {props.data.TIME}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div >
    )


//First div in which I call it 5 times

 return (
        < div >

            <div style={{ width: document.body.scrollWidth / 2.165, backgroundColor: 'white', height: 690, margin: '1% 0', padding: 25, borderRadius: 25, position: 'absolute', left: 11, zIndex: -1 }}>
                <div id='parent' style={{ display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center', width: '100%', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
                    <div style={{ textAlign: 'center', border: '2px solid black', borderRadius: '50px', padding: '0 5%', display: 'flex' }}>
                        <h3 style={{ margin: 0 }}>PLAYLIST</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="cartouchePlaylist" style={{}}>
                    {Playlist ? displayPlaylist() : null}
                </div>

            </div>



        </div>
    );


//Second div in which I call it 6 times

        < div >
            <div style={{ width: document.body.scrollWidth / 2.165, backgroundColor: 'white', height: 360, marginTop: '17.6%', marginLeft: '-48.2%', padding: 25, borderRadius: 25, position: 'absolute', right: 18, top: -118 }}>
                <div id='parent' style={{ display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center', width: '100%', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
                    <div style={{ textAlign: 'center', border: '2px solid black', borderRadius: '50px', padding: '0 5%', display: 'flex' }}>
                        <h3 style={{ margin: 0 }}>CARTOUCHIER</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div style={{}}>
                    {Cartouchier ? displayCartouchier() : null}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use minHeight instead of height, so if the height exceeds it will resize accordingly, but never less than minHeight that we specify.

Comment: Okay, but using minHeight doesn't solve my problem : the height doesn't exceeds, on the contrary, the content of the parent div is too small.

Comment: apply flex:1 to the content you want to take full height of parent.